# Getting an error while copying file from aws EC2 instance to hadoop cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hdfs

[image]

I am not able to run any hadoop command even -ls is also not working getting same error and not able to create directory using
hadoop fs -mkdir users.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one directory in HDFS using the command :

$ hdfs dfs -mkdir "path"

and, then use the given below command to copy data from the local file to HDFS:

$ hdfs dfs -put /root/Hadoop/sample.txt /"your_hdfs_dir_path"

Alternatively, you can also use the below command:

$ hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /root/Hadoop/sample.txt /"your_hdfs_dir_path"